# Importing .csv to postgres. what to do with time?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I would like to import some .csv data into postgres and have issues with a data type :

one of my attributes is birthday:

```
          1968-06-24 00:00:00
```

Therefore I use timestamp, as suggested by pgmodeler. However I always get the message:

```
   postgres=# \connect new_database
   You are now connected to database "new_database" as user "postgres".
   new_database=# \copy players FROM '/Users/Desktop/Rdaten/Data/players.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER
```

Error:

```
   ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NULL"
   CONTEXT:  COPY players, line 267, column birthday: "NULL"
   new_database=#
```

What can I do about that?

Comment: Can you please give a complete csv row sample? And your destination table data structure?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same issue, but I got this error trying to import a CSV where null values were listed as 'NULL' and fixed it by adding "null 'NULL'" to the copy command--by default Postgres expects NULL values to be input as empty strings.